# How to follow redirect to subdomain in capybara RSpec test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, capybara

I want to test the authentication mechanism, which upon success redirects to the subdomain, by example:
1. The login form is located in `http://example.com`
2. Users fill in the form and if credentials are correct, is redirected to `http://zone.example.com`.

My controller action looks like this:

```
def create_session
  if User.authorize(params[:user])
     sign_in user
     redirect_to root_url(subdomain: 'zone')
  else
     redirect_to "#{root_url}#email-login-modal?wrong_password=true"
  end
end
```

The integration test:

```
context "logging in" do
    before(:all) do
      @password = 'test123456'
    end
    let(:user) {create(:user, password: @password)}
    scenario "by email", js: true do
      visit "/"
      page.find("a[href='#email-login-modal']").click
      within("#login-form") do
        fill_in 'user_email', :with => user.email
        fill_in 'user_password', :with => @password
        find("button[type='submit']").click
      end
      expect(page).to have_content user.name
    end
end
```

The login works in development, but the test fails because Capybara does not follow redirection to the subdomain.

Comment: You can try replacing root_url with request.base_url

Comment: Thanks @CaffeineCoder, but as I wrote the controller method works fine, no need to change anything there. The only problem is that the Capybara engine does not follow the redirection to subdomain after successful login (http://zone.example.com), but rather stays in http://example.com (with user properly authorized), as I validated in debugger.

Comment: I know , that's why i said to replace the code and try . Both almost do the the same thing . The difference being , root will always go for the root url (which cannot change) but base_url can be called irrespective of the url even if it's changed . I suspect that's the cause for the tests failing . Trying won't do much harm , will it ? :)

Comment: @CaffeineCoder of course I am glad for your suggestion, but I do not see a way I could make a use of request.base_url. What it gives me is the full URI , it does not accept any params (in particular the subdomain). Could you please elaborate on your concept how to use request.base_url to change the subdomain in the expression: `redirect_to root_url(subdomain: 'zone')`? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This did it for me with Rails 5 and Capybara Chrome driver:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'lvh.me'
```